# How could I get new email and phone number everytime on unit test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, chai

I'm building a unit test for request registration endpoint to one public API, not mine.

I'm working with chai, this is a piece of code:

```
it('should return register information', function(done) {
  let data = {
    User: {
      Name: 'test',
      Email: 'test@test.com',
      CellPhone: '666777888',
      Password: '123456789'
    }
  };

  testApi.register(data).then(res => { ... });
```

Maybe some library?

Comment: It should be easy to generate random strings of letters for names and passwords and digits for cell phones.  Do you really need a library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [facker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker)

```
const faker = require('facker');
it('should return register information', function(done) {
  let data = {
    User: {
      Name: faker.name.findName(),
      Email: faker.internet.email(),
      CellPhone: faker.phone.phoneNumber(),
      Password: '123456789'
    }
  };

  testApi.register(data).then(res => { ... });
```

Comment: Great! Thank you.